# How do you create and apply content_scripts from the browser_action popup in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to create and apply content_scripts from within a browser_action.html popup in Chrome extensions? My aim is to create an extension that allows the user to specify and save css on their current web page, and want to use the browser_action popup as a simple interface. I am aware that content_scripts need to be specified in the manifest.json, and I'm unsure of how to approach this.

Any examples, links or advice is greatly welcomed as I'm still really new to making Chrome Extensions.

Comment: [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4532236), also [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:redder)

Comment: Perhaps also https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-RequestContentScript